# $K$ metrizable implies $C(K)$ separable without SW

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

> Prove $K$ compact Hausdorff metrizable implies $C_\mathbb{R}(K)$ separable

I know how to do this with stone Weierstrass theorem, but I had an interesting idea that I couldn't get to work. The idea is to do the same thing we do to prove $C_\mathbb{R}(\mathbb{R})$ is separable, finite paths of line segments in $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$. The idea is to try do the same thing in $R\times\mathbb{Q}$ where  $R$ is a countable dense subset of $K$.

My flawed execution is as follows: For each $n$ let $N_n$ be a fixed $\frac{1}{n}$-net in $R$.  Let $$S=\bigcup_n \{ f:N_n\rightarrow\mathbb{Q} \text{ extended in a "nice" way to all of $K$}\}$$
(For example using Tietze extension theorem)

$\forall g\in C(K)$, it is uniformly continuous, so we can find $n_0$ such that $$d(x,y)\lt \frac{1}{n_0}\implies |g(x)-g(y)|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{3}$$

Consider $N_{n_0}=\{x_1,...,x_k\}$ and find rationals $y_1,...,y_k$ with $|y_i-g(x_i)|\lt\epsilon/3$. Then for all $x\in K \exists i$ with $d(x,x_i)\lt\frac{1}{n_0} $  so
$$|f(x)-g(x)|\le |f(x)-f(x_i)|+ |f(x_i)-g(x_i)|+|g(x_i)-g(x)|$$
The two terms on the right are less than $\epsilon /3$ but sadly the first one we have no idea. Something significant is wrong with my attempt though because we have the same problem with $K=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: You need to be more specific about the $f$. construct it via a partition of unity associated to the $\frac1n$-net, with this you can continue the proof ($f(x)-f(x_i)$ is $\sum_j \psi_j(x) f(x_j) - f(x_i)$ where only finitely many $j$ are allowed in the sum, namely those that have distance $≤\frac1n$ from $x_i$.  Since $f(x_j)=g(x_j)$ (well, almost) you can use uniform continuity of $g$ to show that $f(x)-f(x_i)$ is small)

Answer (score 1):

The general topology way (using standard theory, see e.g. Engelking (or Kelley) for the details):

- $C_{\Bbb R}(K)$ in the uniform topology in fact has the compact-open topology that has all sets of the form $[C,U]=\{f\mid f[C] \subseteq U\}$ as a subbase, where $C \subseteq K$ is compact and $U \subseteq \Bbb R$ is open.
- $K$ being compact metrisable implies it has a countable base $\mathcal B$ (WLOG closed under finite unions) and $\Bbb R$ has a similar countable base $\mathcal U$ (taking all finite unions of rational open intervals).
- Then $C_{\Bbb R}(K)$ has the countable base $\{[\overline{B},U]\mid B \in \mathcal B, U \in \mathcal U\}$ so is trivially also separable.

Avoid the mess, go for known theory...